# Algorithm for deviations

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, machine-learning

I have to track if given a week full of data integers ( 40, 30, 25, 55, 5, 40, etc )  raise an alert when the deviation from the norm happens (the '5' in the above case). An extra nice thing to have would be to actually learn if 5 is a normal event for that day of the week.

Do you know an implementation in ruby that is meant for this issue? In case this is a classic problem, what's the name of the problem/algorithm?

Comment: This is an example of the classic computer-science problem, "the under-specified algorithm".

Comment: @Jonathan:  Agreed, only because he's asking for a working implementation, not a general idea of how to proceed.

Comment: You need to be way more specific. What do the numbers mean? Is there a general tendency? What defines a deviation? Your solution could be a simple as a running average, or as complex as using a wavelet transform.

Comment: The numbers are the amount of page views in a given day. 

The algorithm should monitor if the code that's been added has been tampered with after deployment (made to register less page views, randomly displayed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very easy thing to calculate, but you will need to tune one parameter. You want to know if any given value is X standard deviations from the mean. To figure this out, calculate the standard deviation (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)), then compare each value's deviation `abs(mean - value)` from the mean to this value. If a value's deviation is say, more than two standard deviations from the mean, flag it.

Edit:

To track deviations by weekday, keep an array of integers, one for each day. Every time you encounter a deviation, increment that day's counter by one. You could also use doubles and instead maintain a percentage of deviations for that day `(num_friday_deviations/num_fridays)` for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is often referred to as "anomaly detection" and there is a lot of work out there if you google for it. The paper [Mining Deviants in Time Series Data Streams](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jsv/Papers/MSV04.miningdeviantsSSDBM.pdf) may help you with your specific needs.

From the abstract:

> We present ﬁrst-known algorithms for identifying deviants on massive data streams. Our algorithms monitor
>   streams using very small space (polylogarithmic in data
>   size) and are able to quickly ﬁnd deviants at any instant,
>   as the data stream evolves over time.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart describes classical ways of doing this sort of thing. As Jonathan Feinberg commented, there are different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the algorithm could be as simple as "calculate standard deviation."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

However, any analysis you do should be specific to the data set. You should inspect historical data to get at the right algorithm. Standard deviation won't be a good measure at all unless your data is normally distributed. Your data might even be such that you just want to look for numbers above a certain max value... it really depends.

So, my advice to you is:

1) Google for **statistics overview** and read up on basic statistics.

2) Inspect any historical data you have.

3) Come up with some reasonable measure of an odd number.

4) Test your measure against your historical data and see if it highlights the numbers you think it should.

5) Repeat steps 2-4 as necessary to refine your algorithm.